# Description and MIB files for .1.3.6.1.4.1.15227.1.3.1.1.6.0 and .1.3.6.1.4.1.15227.1.3.1.1.7.0

Tags: snmp, mib, oid

I could not find detail description for following OIDs.

.1.3.6.1.4.1.15227.1.3.1.1.6.0

.1.3.6.1.4.1.15227.1.3.1.1.7.0

And, Where do I download for MIB files for these OIDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.4.1.15227 says :

- OID: /ISO/Identified-Organization/6/1/4/1/15227
- Description:     Venus Info Tech Inc.

So I thing you need to contact the Venus Info Tech Inc. organization. I presume they are at  http://www.venustech.com.cn/en/

Comment: Thanks for reply. I don't have device from Venus Info Tech Inc. I am testing with simulator and checking MIBs downloaded from Internet. That's why I am searching MIB including detail description for above OIDs.

Comment: Where did you get that particular OID number from : From a device or from a MIB? If from a device what do you see when you walk it like snmpwalk   -M +.  -m +ALL -v 2c -c public  some_host  1.3.6.1.4.1.15227.1.3.1.1.7.0

Comment: MIB is VENUS-NIPS-MIB.mib file. I can see above OID number by "Getif" software. But I can not see full description for above OID. What these OID means and What this values are used for? Thanks.

Comment: If you have the MIB file, you have the authoritative source of information. If the MIB autor didn't add enough information to the MIB, then you should contact them and ask for clarification. No-one on the Internet is likely to know anything about someone else's MIB design.

Comment: Agree with @Jolta. Tools like "Getif" may present the MIB info in a easier-to-read way; but they cant give 'extra' descriptions beyond what the MIB file contains.

Comment: @Jolta, So only way to get full description from MIB is to ask from MIB's Vendor? No other ways?

Comment: Yes. (I was going to put that as a single-word comment, but stackoverflow won't allow me to.)